# Rows counter of file

Tags: scripting

Hi I'm trying to script a code that return the numbers of lines in a file.txt...anyone can help me? Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1

NROWS=$(wc -l)$1
```

Comment: Why would you want a script for that? That's what `wc -l` does. Your script, even if corrected, doesn't add anything at all. If this is just a step in order to do something else, please explain what your final aim is and we can probably give a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$(COMMAND)` is the syntax of a [command substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution). That is, the entire command needs to be within the parentheses.
- [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)!
- Non-exported variables are `lower_case` by convention.

The result: `row_count="$(wc --lines "$1")"`.

Answer (score 1):

The `$1` should be inside the `$(...)` call

```
NROWS=$(wc -l $1)
```

The syntax `$(...)` basically means "run the command and return the output as a string", which you can then assign to a variable.

So this command would mean "run the command `wc -l $1` and store the results in the variable `NROWS`"